# Use Printable String when generating a certificate with Bouncy Castle

Tags: java, format, certificate, bouncycastle, string-formatting

I'm successfully signing a x509v3 certificate from a CSR using BouncyCastle in Java, but I have a problem: the string format from some of the certificate fields (Subject in this case) is `UTF8_STRING` and I need it to be `PRINTABLE_STRING`

When generating the certificate I use an `X509v3CertificateBuilder` and a `CertificateFactory` objects plus a `JcaX509ExtensionUtils` to add some extensions to it.

Any help on how to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the types of the `X500Name`'s attributes using the following snippet:

```
X500Name name = new X500Name ("O=org,CN=somename,L=city,C=country");
RDN[] rdns = name.getRDNs(); 
for (int i = 0; i < rdns.length; i++){
    AttributeTypeAndValue[] attrs = rdns[i].getTypesAndValues();
    for (int j = 0; j < attrs.length; j++) {
        attrs[j] = new AttributeTypeAndValue(attrs[j].getType(), new DERPrintableString(attrs[j].getValue()));
    }
    rdns[i] = new RDN(attrs);            
}
name = new X500Name(rdns);
```

This is based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49792047/5256872